# How to prevent URLs from exceeding the HTTP limit?

Tags: api, http, url, rest, get

A Car model with following attributes is present on server

```
  name: string
  uid: string, maxlength 200 chars
  color: string
```

I have an API call to get the list of all cars as below

```
/cars.json
```

Now I need to modify this, and add a parameter which will take a comma separated list of car uids as below

```
/cars.json?car_uids=car1,car2,car3...
```

I need to make sure the URL for this doesn't exceed the HTTP limit. Suggestions please.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to work over GET? What is the reason you cannot use POST for this?

If you honestly can't use POST, is there any way you can make the unique identifiers shorter? Perhaps using an autogenerated primary key?

Comment: @RickvanBodegraven the /cars.json is a GET request, so I was probably thinking of going with GET, but if there is no way out, I have a backup plan of creating a new resource as POST and accept the parameters in the request body.

Comment: ok. That is what I would do, as it essentially provides you with an 'unlimited' number of filters. It also takes away some of the more irritating aspects of querystring parameter handling :) Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296421/rest-complex-applications/1297275#1297275