# How to use Session in a spring application using Jersey Spring servlet?

Tags: java, spring, session, servlets, jersey

I am using Jersey Spring servlet for my application and I want to use session to capture my login credentials. HttpSession can be one option but I dont want to use javax.servlet.http as I am already using jersey servlet. Also I dont want to code it in the client side using Javascript.

**Is there any way to acheive this**???

Comment: Spring Security and Spring Session?

Comment: read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296421/rest-complex-applications/1297275#1297275)

Comment: @Rohit,@chrylis Thanks for your reply. I am still following up your suggested links.